# HTTPS - Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/

Tags: python, kazoo

I am trying to install kazoo:
I tried the following options: `pip install kazoo` and `pip install "kazoo==2.6.1"`

Upon running this command I am getting the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking kazoo
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement kazoo
Cleaning up...
  No distributions at all found for kazoo
  Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Following is the content of `/root/.pip/pip.log`:

```
/usr/bin/pip run on Wed Jul 14 09:15:11 2021
Downloading/unpacking kazoo==2.6.1
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/kazoo/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/kazoo/: 403 Client Error: [[[!!! 
BREAKING CHANGE !!!]]] Support for clients that do not support Server Name Indication is temporarily disabled and will be permanently deprecated soon. See https://status.python.org/incidents/hzmjhqsdjqgb and https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978 [[[!!! END BREAKING CHANGE !!!]]]
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/kazoo/ when looking for download links for kazoo==2.6.1
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: 403 Client Error: [[[!!! BREAKING CHANGE !!!]]] Support for clients that do not support Server Name Indication is temporarily disabled and will be permanently deprecated soon. See https://status.python.org/incidents/hzmjhqsdjqgb and https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978 [[[!!! END BREAKING CHANGE !!!]]]
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for kazoo==2.6.1
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
URLs to search for versions for kazoo==2.6.1:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/kazoo/2.6.1
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/kazoo/
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/kazoo/2.6.1
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/kazoo/2.6.1: 403 Client Error: [[[!!! BREAKING CHANGE !!!]]] Support for clients that do not support Server Name Indication is temporarily disabled and will be permanently deprecated soon. See https://status.python.org/incidents/hzmjhqsdjqgb and https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978 [[[!!! END BREAKING CHANGE !!!]]]
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/kazoo/2.6.1 when looking for download links for kazoo==2.6.1
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/kazoo/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/kazoo/: 403 Client Error: [[[!!! BREAKING CHANGE !!!]]] Support for clients that do not support Server Name Indication is temporarily disabled and will be permanently deprecated soon. See https://status.python.org/incidents/hzmjhqsdjqgb and https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978 [[[!!! END BREAKING CHANGE !!!]]]
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/kazoo/ when looking for download links for kazoo==2.6.1
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement kazoo==2.6.1
Cleaning up...
Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
No distributions at all found for kazoo==2.6.1
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
"~/.pip/pip.log" 34L, 3388C
```

I read a few articles about it which talks about SSL but here I am already using HTTPS

I also tried `pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple kazoo` but nothing worked.

pip --version : `pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

python --version : `Python 2.7.6`

I am running this in my local system on macOS Catalina 10.15.7 in a Docker container

I tried upgrading pip:
`pip install pip --upgrade` it also gives the same error:

```
 Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
 Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
 Downloading/unpacking pip
 Cleaning up...
 No distributions at all found for pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
 Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I am new to python. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you update `pip` and try again? `pip install pip --upgrade`

Comment: Can you share more details about the environment in which you are installing the package, such as OS, cloud or local, etc?

Comment: Did you read the error message? Which parts of it do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.